# Правильный ли алгоритм решения?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Последние 2 недели занимаюсь изучением C#, ранее опыта программирования не было. Используется учебник Microsoft Visual C# 2008 под авторством К. Утсона и К... В процессе изучения дошел до задачи:
Напишите клиентское консольное приложение для библиотеки Ch10CardLib, вытягивающее сразу пять карт из перетасованной колоды (объекта Deck). В случае если все пять карт относятся к одной масти, это клиентское приложение должно отображать их названия на экране в месте с текстом "Flush!" (Флэш!); в противном случае оно должно прекращать свою работу после просмотра 50 карт вместе с текстом "No flush" (Нет флэша).
Как я понимаю алгоритм должен быть примерно таким(с уже готовыми объектами, методами, и библиотекой):

1. "Вытянуть 5 карт (поочередно, т.к. одновременно не умею) карт из Deck"
2. Сохранить их в массив
3. Сравнить масти в самом массиве или вывести элементы массива в отдельные переменные и сравнить уже их
4. Ну и соответственно если есть совпадения в мастях "выдать "Флэш"", если нет "выдать"Нет Флэша"".

Правилен ли мой способ решения и какие  нем есть ошибки (почему то я уверен их в нем не мало). Жду Ваших подсказок. Готовое решение не хотелось бы получать т.к. хочется дойти самому.

Answer (score 2):

В общем правильно, ты просто условия задачи разложил на подпункты решение, только с опытом с сможешь видеть более подходящие решение, а пока делать "так что бы работало правильно".
По твоей реализации, уже можно будет сказать типа, "здесь лучше так, потому что..", "здесь, это лишнее, а тут лучше вообще нечего не менять" =)

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм верный, но не оптимальный.
UPD: Т.к. автор не хочет готового решения, убираю его ( доступно в истории изменений )

Comment: Тоже спасибо. До UDP увидел =), что я должен был в итоге сделать. Направление понятно. Не запомнил, но буду уже думать по Вашему способу реализации.

Comment: Советую, глубже вникать в условия задачи:<br>
Что-бы набор карт был Флешем, нужно что-бы масти 2,3,4,5 совпадали с мастью 1 карты.<br>
Отсюда и получаем, что впринципи, в общем случае, вытаскивать заранее все 5 карт - не зачем.